# Lookup field not show all columns Dynamics 365 business central

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-nav

I'm new in business central.

Create a table and list page. My table have 2 fields:

```
Code, Code [20]

Description, Text [50]
```

Then I create a `tableExtension` and add a new field and a table relation to my table. Works fine, but when I lookup show only field code.

I need show my two field in lookup.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are **field Groups**.

**Field groups** allow add field to use in your lookup.

In your table you don´t have defined the section **fieldGroups**.

In your case you need add this

[image]